# Can't display video file in react-native on Android device

Tags: android-videoview, react-native

I have following issue. I try to display video file with extension `*.mp4` in react-native app running on android device using `react-native-video` component.

I managed to reference this video and I can hear sound from video file, but I don't know how to display an actual video image.

Here is my code for this component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
var Video = require('react-native-video').default;

class VideoScene extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Video
          style={styles.backgroundVideo}
          repeat
          resizeMode='cover'
          source={require('../assets/SampleVideo.mp4')}
        />
     </View>
    );
  }
};

// Later on in your styles..           
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
  flex: 1,
},
backgroundVideo: {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: 0,
  left: 0,
  bottom: 0,
  right: 0,
 },
});


export default VideoScene;
```

My guess that there is some issue with styles, but can't figure out which one.

Thank you for any suggestions/help that can help solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use an absolute style, you have to provide width and height since it won't adapt as flex does.

I'm guessing you also want it to be full screen. In that case you'll need the dimensions of the screen:

```
render() {
    const w = Dimensions.get('window').width;
    const h = Dimensions.get('window').height;
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Video
                style={[styles.backgroundVideo, {width: w, height: h}]}
                repeat
                resizeMode='cover'
                source={require('../assets/SampleVideo.mp4')}
        />
        </View>
    );
}
```